# Creating a displayPort Signal

Tags: signal, display, displayport

I am attempting to create a displayPort source signal from scratch.  I just read through the 1.1 Specification (which is outdated and free on the displayPort website) and it gave a decent overview.  What I am lacking is an "implementation guide".  Specifically I want to know the sequence of events that I must do electrically to effectively send the pixel data.  For example when I plug in and power up, first I must send or receive "x" (or whatever).  Then I must do "y" over the "z" pin...etc...etc.  I attempted to sign up with displayPort to get free additional documentation, but that costs $5000.  If someone can point me to a book, guide, or website that gives more specific implementation data, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately, standards are just that: expensive to buy the text that tells you what they are/how they work/how to implement them. Honestly, trying to implement it from the ground up is not going to be the best experience.

Comment: Of what purpose does this serve?  Perhaps you can study the Xilinx and Altera solutions. e.g. http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/application_notes/xapp1178-displayport-reference-design.pdf. Are you familiar with ISI precompensation and TI's solution?

Comment: Thank you for the info.  The purpose...well.  It is more of an experiment.  I have heard that TV's and monitors will no longer support analog signals in the coming years.  If that is true, and if my question does not have an answer, it is not good news for the average tinkerer.  Like so many technologies that we all now depend on but do not understand, only companies that are in the "circle of knowledge" can be really be innovative with them.

Comment: You're not going to be able to do this with anything but an FPGA, at which point there are free IP cores available for standards like HDMI/DVI and possibly DisplayPort. Building this IP from the ground up is not going to be trivial, and if you can get a free IP core, it's not worth the effort IMHO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to answer my own question based on the feedback I have received.  Apparently this is not a reasonable goal and there is not a straight forward, user friendly document that would help the average person create a signal.